# Javascript promise: can a parameter passed to fulfill go out of scope?

Tags: javascript, promise

I was following a javascript tutorial on promises, [here](https://www.toptal.com/javascript/javascript-promises), specifically this code (which simulates a die's throw):

```
function dieToss() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;  
}

function tossASix() {
  return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
    var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    if (n === 6) {
      fulfill(n);
    } else {
      reject(n);
    }
  });
}

function logAndTossAgain(toss) {
  console.log("Tossed a " + toss + ", need to try again.");
  return tossASix();
}

function logSuccess(toss) {
  console.log("Yay, managed to toss a " + toss + ".");
}

function logFailure(toss) {
  console.log("Tossed a " + toss + ". Too bad, couldn't roll a six");
}

tossASix()
  .then(null, logAndTossAgain)   //Roll first time
  .then(null, logAndTossAgain)   //Roll second time
  .then(logSuccess, logFailure); //Roll third and last time
```

I think it is clear what it's doing, but, as a test, I changed the last few lines to this instead

```
tossASix()
  .then(logSuccess, logAndTossAgain)   //Roll first time
  .then(logSuccess, logAndTossAgain)   //Roll second time
  .then(logSuccess, logFailure); //Roll third and last time
```

If I understand promises correctly (please bear with me here as I'm still trying to get my head around them) I would have thought that when I get a 6 at the first throw, the output would have been

```
Yay, managed to toss a 6.
Yay, managed to toss a 6.
Yay, managed to toss a 6.
```

but in fact what I get is

```
Yay, managed to toss a 6.
Yay, managed to toss a undefined.
Yay, managed to toss a undefined.
```

Why is that?
Does it mean that after the first call to logSuccess (which is to say fulfill) the parameter n goes out of scope? If so why? Has it got anything to do with the fact that the promise is fulfilled only once and that's it?

Answer (score 1):

`then` accepting two arguments: the first one is `resolve` callback and the second is `reject` callback, and returns a new `Promise`.

Since you've get a `6` on first call of `tossASix` it wont call `logAndTossAgain` because you pass it as a `reject` callback and just keep on logging `undefined` values because function `logSuccess` provided as a `resolve`  doesn't return nothing.

You can read more about chaining of promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining).

Answer (score 0):

```
1: tossASix()
2:   .then(logSuccess, logAndTossAgain)   //Roll first time
3:   .then(logSuccess, logAndTossAgain)   //Roll second time
4:   .then(logSuccess, logFailure); //Roll third and last time
```

When `tossASix` resolve/fullfil, `logSuccess` at line 2 called with argument `6`, and the return (thats undefined) passed as argument into `logSuccess` at line 3 and happen again at line 4.

If you wanna see return like this

```
Yay, managed to toss a 6.
Yay, managed to toss a 6.
Yay, managed to toss a 6.
```

you need to return `n` at `logSuccess` function so the value passed into the next function.

Comment: yes I think I got it, I actually added a `return toss;` to logSuccess after reading @Panama Prophet's comment and it works. I didn't realize that the .then function kept returning something, in our case undefined